# Parse a JSON FILE in Scala(2.10.1) using Play

Tags: json, scala, parsing, sbt

I am a complete newbie in scala, all I want to do here is have a JSON file simply parsed using scala and print the same. I am facing an error on compiling which I am not able to solve. Thanks in advance for any help on this. PFB the scala code, SBT file, JSON file and error:

**json_example.scala**

```
import scala.io.Source
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json._


object Test extends App  {


val line :String = "Foo";

val filename = "users.json"
for (line <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines().mkString) {
println(line);
val json: JsValue = Json.parse(line);

 }
 }
```

JSON File (**users.json**)

```
{"users":[
    {"ID":"1","firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"ID":"2","firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"ID":"3","firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
    {"ID":"1","firstName":"Stewie", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"ID":"2","firstName":"Chris", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"ID":"3","firstName":"Louis", "lastName":"Jones"}
    {"ID":"2","firstName":"Brian", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"ID":"3","firstName":"Meg", "lastName":"Jones"}

]}
```

**SBT file (simple.sbt)**

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).

settings(
name := "JSON_GRAPHX",
version := "1.0",
scalaVersion := "2.10.1",

libraryDependencies ++= Seq("com.github.scala-incubator.io" %% "scala-io-file" % "0.4.2",
                       "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.3.4"),

                      resolvers += "Typesafe Repo" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"


)
```

**Error**

```
[info] Set current project to JSON_GRAPHX (in build file:/F:/Graphx_app/JSON_GRAPHX/)
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to F:\Graphx_app\JSON_GRAPHX\target\scala-2.10\classes...
[error] F:\Graphx_app\JSON_GRAPHX\json_example.scala:15: overloaded method value parse with alternatives:
[error]   (input: Array[Byte])play.api.libs.json.JsValue <and>
[error]   (input: String)play.api.libs.json.JsValue
[error]  cannot be applied to (Char)
[error]  val json: JsValue = Json.parse(line);
[error]                           ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 4 s, completed Aug 18, 2016 8:51:22 PM
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build the JSON object, you can call the `parse` method directly in the `String` returned by `mkString`. Something like:

```
val json = Json.parse(Source.fromFile(filename).getLines().mkString)
```

By doing:

```
for (line <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines().mkString)
```

You are actually iterating over all characters of the Json String - that's why you get the error that the `parse` method cannot be applied to a Char.

Once you have the JSON object, you can print it minified:

```
println(Json.stringify(json))
```

Or you can print it in a readable format:

```
println(Json.prettyPrint(son))
```

Comment: This is a perfect solution. Wondering as to why this was not accepted

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much for the help @virsox. Sorry for the delayed response.